# Group Numbering With Optional Blocks in a Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way to have an expression in brackets *not* be caught in a group?

E.g. i have an expression something like this:

```
(A(B|C)?) D (E(F|G)?)
```

Take note of the optional blocks `(B|C)?` and `(F|G)?` needing brackets.
I'm not interested in what was caught in these groups. All i want is to catch the full first and last block.

But because of the optional blocks, the group numbering will change and i can't tell if `(E(F|G)?)` was caught as group 2 or 3.

Can i tell the expression to ignore the optional parts in the result groups, so the group numbering will stay the same? Or can i make optional catches always appear in groups - even when they're null?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(E(F|G)?)` will always be caught as group 3.  The numbering is determined by the order of opening parentheses in the pattern string, which is:

```
(A(B|C)?) D (E(F|G)?)
^ ^         ^ ^
1 2         3 4
```

If `(B|C)` does not occur in the input string then `group(2)` will return null, but the subsequent groups will not be renumbered.

The only groups that do not influence numbering are non-capturing groups, e.g.

```
(A(?:B|C)?) D (E(?:F|G)?)
^             ^
1             2
```

Example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(A(B|C)?) D (E(F|G)?)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("A D EG");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.err.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.err.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.err.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.err.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

Output:

```
A
null
EG
G
```

Comment: You're right.  
Apparently i was misled by my eclipse plug-in QuickREx, which only showed 3 groups (but with index 1, 3 and 4). But the non-capturing bit still comes in very handy to reduce noise.

Answer (score 9):

There are non-capturing groups `(?:…)`:

```
(A(?:B|C)?) D (E(?:F|G)?)
```

The match of such a group can not be referenced.